# Кеширование или что? Laravel

Tags: laravel

Есть страничка где юзер просматривает книгу и при нажатии на кнопку удалить ему показывается другая страница, на которой написано, что такая-то книга успешно удалена. При успешном удалении очищается сессия(проверял там null) 
Если обновить страницу, то редирект срабатывает, если нажать на кнопку назад, то не срабатывает
Почему при нажатии на браузерную кнопку назад не исполняется код внутри функции ?

```
    public function KillBook(Request $request)
        {
            $book = $request->session()->get('book');

            if ($book == null) {
                return redirect()->action('BookController@index');
            }
...
    }
```

Как в документации тоже пробовал. Если обновить страницу, то редирект срабатывает, если нажать на кнопку назад, то не срабатывает

```
    if ($request->session()->has('book')) {
    //
}
```

Сам процесс с книгой может быть и глупый, но как быть, к примеру если необходимо сделать проверку на то что пользователь авторизован.

```
if (Auth::check())
       return 1;
   else
       return 0;
```

Comment: Это хитрый браузер. FF этим очень грешит последнее время: в ряде случаев кнопка назад не приводит к новому запросу.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что это браузер грешит.

Comment: А вы проверьте по логу доступа apache.

Comment: В логе фиксируется доступ к нужной странице

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение проблемы. Нужно создать фильтр который будет запрещать кэширование.

Надо создать класс в `app/http/middleware`

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cache
{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      $response = $next($request);
        $response->headers->set('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
        $response->headers->set('Pragma','no-cache');
        $response->headers->set('Expires','Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Добавить его в `Kernel.php`

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
   'no-cache' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cache::class,   
];
```

В роутах нужно добавить

```
Route::get('/book','BookController@index',['middleware' => 'no-cache']);
```

Comment: А при чем тут, говорите, куки? Вы в явном виде выставляете **заголовки** связанные с кэшированием. Как следствие, изначальная проблема все-таки в кэше.

Comment: Не причём. перепутал. Но тем не менее это полностью решает проблему.

Comment: Так может стоит подправить ответ? ;)

Comment: С мобилы не удобно

Answer (score 0):

Браузер при переходе назад по истории не выполняет новый запрос а лишь показывает прошлый результат.
Так же нету смысла переводить пользователя на другую страницу для информирования о удалении книги, вы можете сделать редирект на ту же страницу с показыванием flash сообщения.

Comment: Смысла может в этом и нет. Но мне необходимо понять почему не выполняется функция в контроллере. Например в интернет магазинах при оформлении заказа, аналогичный функционал работает. В логах апача посмотрел, браузер отправляет запрос на сервер.

Comment: Странно, сейчас сам попробовал.
Сделал редирект с 1 страницы на другую. И после того нажал на кнопку "Назад" в браузере, и первая ссылка была проигнорирована и сразу вернуло меня на запрос пере первой ссылкой.